# Linux commandline to add & move files to a compressed archive

Tags: linux, command-line, compression, archive

I'm searching a linux methode to add & move files to a compressed archive via command line.
`-tar` cannot add files to a compressed archive
`-zip` can do, 
but the compressesion is weak. `(zip -u -r -q -9 -m destination.zip /sourcefolder)`
archive with `tar=5GB` same files compressed with `zip=22GB (-9)`
-`7zip` cannot 'move' to archive.

what is the best way to 'add' and 'move' a folder to a compressed archive?

Comment: WDYM that 7zip can't move to archive? https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/sdel.htm

Comment: I found that site as well.
-sdel does not work. (maybee just Windows?)
it is even not listed under 7z --help

Comment: According to the [changelog](https://www.7-zip.org/history.txt), it was added in version 9.30 alpha.

Comment: I guess the linux command line builds of original 7zip are very recent, so maybe p7zip never implemented it.